# Custom form in theme template displaying internal server error upon submission

Tags: theme-development, forms, internal-server-error

I have a custom form in WordPress theme template but it is displaying internal server error upon submission. There is no error in error.log file regarding this submission. I am hosting my website on bluehost and here is my form

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/formprocessing.php">    
        <label for="first-name">Name*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="volunteerName" required/>
        <label for="address">Address*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="address" name="volunteerAddress" required/>
        <label for="email">Email*</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="volunteerEmail" required/>
        <input class="form-control" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id=""/>
</form>
```

In formprocessing.php file I am just displaying some text and upon submission it redirects to this template file but displaying Internal server error.

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['volunteerName'])){

echo "Form working";
exit;

}
?>
```

I have spent a lot of time to figure out this issue but still not able to figure out this. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that the only code in `formprocessing.php`?

Comment: Yes as I am just testing this process @SallyCJ

Comment: Your code works fine for me, so try contacting the hosting support team - they might be able to help you. Or, instead of sending the data to `formprocessing.php`, you could just use the `init` hook to process the data/submission.